# Laravel 5.3 logging a new Facebook user from the second time

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am using socialite to integrate the login with Facebook function. Here is my code:

```
public function handleProviderCallback()
{

    try {
        $socialUser = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return redirect('/dashboard');
    }


    /*section1 : i check if the user exists in the db, and if no then 
    I save this user in the db */

    $user = User::where('facebook_id', $socialUser->getId())->first();
    if (!$user) {
        User::create([
            'facebook_id' => $socialUser->getId(),
            'name' => $socialUser->getName(),
            'email' => $socialUser->getEmail(),
        ]);

        Auth::loginUsingId($socialUser->id);
        return redirect()->intended('/dashboard');
        }

        /* end of section one */


        else{
        if(Auth::loginUsingId($user->id)){
            return redirect()->intended('/dashboard');
        }
    }


}
```

The problem is: I login with a new user, the data is added to the database and I am redirected to the dashboard, but I am not logged in. After I try logging in again (when the user already exists in the database) I am successfully logged in. Why? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with following line. You have to pass the user id in the database, not the Facebook id.

`Auth::loginUsingId($socialUser->id);`

Update as following

```
$newUser = User::create(...);
Auth::loginUsingId($newUser->id);
```

Comment: I got an error
    at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Trying to get property of non-object', '/Users/andrei/Desktop/service/service.dev/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php', '104', array('socialUser' => object(User), 'user' => null)) in RegisterController.php line 104.  (for the line Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);)

Comment: @AndrewT The `create` function will return the created instance. From the error it looks like it didn't create an entry. Hope you are storing the return value of `create` function as `$user = User::create(...)`. Can u check whether entry created in the DB?

Comment: the data is added successfully to the DB. The problem is that I cannot login immediately with that user as I am getting an error after I changed the code above, or I was redirected to the dashboard but was not logged in and I don't understand why. I suppose that $user is created only after I am out of the if statement, so I can not use the $user inside my if statement

Comment: if I return to the login screen of my website, I can login with my user when it is in my database. I don't enter the if(!$user) statement and everything works

Comment: the problem is in this line  Auth::loginUsingId($socialUser->id);
It does not log in the created user

Comment: Can you add `dd($user)` after this line `$user = User::create(...);` and check

Comment: it returns null as I am checking the state when $user is null

Comment: check the image below please. I am debugging the socialUser and I am returned all his data

Comment: ok I think you are confusing `$user` with `$user = User::where('facebook_id', $socialUser->getId())->first();`. This is not what I'm saying. May be change the variable like below & print it. `$newUser = User::create(...); dd($newUser); Auth::loginUsingId($newUser->id);`

Comment: The assignment of $newUser to User::create and logging in the $newUser works! Thank you very much!

Comment: @AndrewT Glad it helped you. I updated the variable name in the answer